# trying to get screen size with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create an "image" in a php file depending on the screen size

here's the html file

```
<div class="myImage">
    <img src="testimage.php" alt="testimage" name="image" class="imgA">
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="testimage.js"></script>
```

then the js

```
var getScreenSize = function(){
    var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
    var screenHeight= screen.availHeight;
    $.ajax({
        url:'testimagesize.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            sw: screenWidth,
            sh: screenHeight,
            method:'screensize'
        },
        success: function(result){
            if(result=="ok"){
                alert('ok');
            }else{
                alert('ko');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
getScreenSize();
```

then the 'testimagesize.php'

```
if($_POST['method']=='screensize')
{
    echo 'ok';
    $width = $_POST['sw'];
    $height= $_POST['sh'];
}
```

and finally the testimage.php where I want to get the width & height

```
require'testimagesize.php';

header('Content-type: image/png');
$image = imagecreate($width, $height);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$color2 = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 150, 150);
for($i=0;$i<200;$i=$i+25){
    for ($a=0; $a<=1600; $a=$a+60) { 
        for ($b=-50; $b<=350 ; $b=$b+60) { 
            $line1b = imageellipse($image, $a, $b, $i, $i, $color2);
        }
    }
}
imagecolortransparent($image, $color);
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

My problem is, the terminal tells me "Undefined index: method" on the line 1 of the 'testimagesize.php' and I can't understand why ... And obviously, my last file don't know who $width or $height are ... undefined variables.

Thanks for your help

Comment: There are easier ways to create a full screen background image, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: What happens when you `print_r($_POST)`?